# VBA code: Set Match Destination Formatting as the default paste in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write VBA code in excel to make Match Destination Formatting as the default paste option.

I've trying cut and paste code from a site

```
Sub PasteWithDestinationFormatting()
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

I got runtime 1004 error 'method range not specified'. What is the problem with this code please?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `xlPasteValues` requires certain support from the program that put the data in the clipboard. E.g. copying from Word will work, e.g. copying from Firefox won't.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg, but the 1004 occurs when there isn't anything in the clipboard too when I run the code in the module

Comment: That is fully covered by what I said. There is no data in a supported format in the clipboard, so `xlPasteValues` cannot work.

Comment: In layman's terms, you have not copied anything, so you can't paste anything.

Comment: @GSerg and GMalc, Ok yes I understand, thanks. I was trying to write code so that excel will automatically paste with destination formatting when typing "ctrl + v" is there a better way than this please?

Comment: Yes, using vba, you have to either use `PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)`, or you can use `PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)` and  `PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats)` in two separate lines of code.

Comment: @GMalc, that's done it, great. Thank you!